# How to dynamically replace some string values with values from a while loop with PHP

Tags: php

Goal: To replace the names in the following string:- Jack,+,Sarah,-,Drew with integer values from a mysql table while loop to get:- 100+20-30
then to use that string to calculate the result :- 90

I suspect I need to use a variable variable but I'm stuck as to how to implement it. Any pointers would be appreciated.

What I currently have: (I have not included the full code as the variable outputs are echoed correctly so have posted only relevant part)

```
    ... while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3)){
                    $virtualfunction = $row['virtualfunction'];
                    $meterdisplayname = $row['meterdisplayname'];                       

                $frag = explode(",", $virtualfunction);
                for($i = 0; $i < count($frag); $i++){
                    echo "Fragment $i = $frag[$i] <br />";

                    $sql4 = "SELECT lastusage FROM rm_meters
                    WHERE (meterdisplayname = '$frag[$i]')
                    AND metertype <>'Virtual' "; 
                        $database->setQuery($sql4);
                        $result4 = $database->query($sql4);
                        $database->close();


        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result4)){
                    $lastusage = $row['lastusage'];

                if (($frag[$i] == "+")||($frag[$i] == "-")){
                    $operator = $frag;
                }
                //  $total = // -- Not sure how to build this -- //

                }

        echo $total;

        }               
        }
```

Comment: Please add your input array and expected output array. That might help us to understand better.

Comment: Do NOT use a variable variable.  Generate a lookup array.

Comment: Are you wanting the actual code? As I pointed out in introduction the input array would be of format: Jack,+,Sarah,-,Drew and the while loop would return values such as 10,20,30 and the goal is to replace the values Jack Sarah and Drew with 10,20 and 30 then use that string to do a calculation

Comment: Put the names into one array, the integers into another - then you can use str_replace to get this part done in one go. As for calculating the result based on a “formula” in a string value, that is a more complex issue, please do some research on that. Your input data seems to come from some sort of meter/measuring device, so if the data format that delivers is predictable, this might be one of the few cases where `eval` could do the job without too much potential for harm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a replacement array to find names and replace them associative.

```
$str ="Jack,+,Sarah,-,Drew";
$repl = ['Jack' => 100, 'Sarah' => 20, 'Drew' => 30];

$res="";
Foreach(explode(",", $str) as $val){
    // Replace if val is in replace array else just add Val to result string
    $res .= (isset($repl[$val]) ? $repl[$val] : $val);
}
// $res is now "100+20-30"
$res= eval('return '.$res.';'); // calculate the math string
Echo $res;
```

https://3v4l.org/YpNhO

This method will also support other more advanced operands than just + and -.
Here I use `() *` and square root. https://3v4l.org/eapcU

Comment: Both the above methods solved my problem(s) and I will use both of them on different sites for different purposes. Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I left out MySQL from the equation, and just focused on the string processing and calculation part. I hope this is what you're trying to achieve:

```
$input = "-,Jack,+,Sarah,-,Drew";
$replacements = [
    "Jack" => 100,
    "Sarah" => 20,
    "Drew" => 30
];

$inputParts = explode(",", $input);
$result = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($inputParts); $i += 2) {

    if ($inputParts[$i] == '-') {
        $result -= $replacements[$inputParts[$i + 1]];
    } else {
        $result += $replacements[$inputParts[$i + 1]];
    }
}
print($result);
```

Comment: Your method is limited to + and -. I think you should add the other too.

Comment: Without further info from OP it is hard to guess what operands would actually be needed. This covers the use case in OP's example.